# How to get member variable in event handler called from a prototype function in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, closures

My problem is simplified to something like this:

```
function ClassA(){
  this.x = 2;
}

ClassA.prototype = {
  init: function(){
    $(window).scroll(this.handleScroll);
  },
  handleScroll: function(){
    ... // how to get this.x, this is now referring to window and I cannot pass parameter from window.scroll
  }
}
```

Comment: Please search before posting, there are at least 20 questions on this here, with answers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should've thought harder!